# How to configure Network for machines to have access to local wireless printers and devices

Tags: router, switch, private-network

I have several computers in my network that have public static IP's.  I also have a number of computers and devices that have private IP's, some static and some dynamically assigned by the router.

I would like to know what I need to do to efficiently have access to the local private network (the printers, devices and other local computers) by my computers that have public static IP's.

Currently I have the following equipment:

```
2 Linksys E2500 wireless routers
2 PCNet 8 port switches
1 Arris DG860 4 Port Cable Modem (Connected to the ISP)
```

When I run the Linksys router network from the cable modem only I have sufficient bandwidth performance.  Plugging a cable into the port switch gives all my computers access to all the other devices that are connected to the local private network (supplied by the Linksys router), but my bandwidth to the Internet becomes unbearably slow… almost nill.

To have access to the local devices I use the `ifconfig` command to add a secondary IP to the NIC.

Secondary IP (for private network access):

```
$ sudo ifconfig eth0:192 192.168.1.50 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

Can someone advise how this came done, either with the current equipment or what equipment might need to be added to the network to achieve this.

Currently I either have a slow network, then all my computers can use the printers and scanners in the local network, or I have to remove the RJ45 connector from the switch and lose connection to my local private network and download my print jobs to a computer connected wireless for performing the printing.

**All my main computers are running Linux.**  I connect Windows and MAC OS periodically, for performing repairs for customers, or allowing guess access to my network and the Internet.

Comment: I'm suspecting your PCNet switch is the culprit. I couldn't find anything about it on the Web. Have you tried connecting everything to the router's Ethernet ports without the PCNet switches? Also, you practically have three routers in a home network -- the DG860 is effectively a modem+router+switch+wireless access point combo device. How are the Linksys routers connected to each other and to the DG860? Are they connected via the WAN interfaces?

Comment: It's a business.  The 2nd wireless router is installed in one of the workshops for stronger signal.  A network cable runs from the main computer room to one of the workshops and duplicates the setup in the workshop.  I'll eliminate that cable and connectivity to avoid confusion.  At present it's just one of everything.

If I connect the computers with the WAN static IP's to the Linksys router, they loose Internet connection to the public IP's.

I'll try any configuration you think will work and give you the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried the working resolution during my weeks of working and trying to resolve this problem.  It appears the problem was the method of testing.  The computer from which the testing was performed needed to be rebooted to recognize the change and connectivity.

**Working configuration:**

Connect the router (which in this case is the `Linksys Router`) to one of the ports of the Internet connection coming directly from the ISP provider (in this case the `Arris DG860 Cable Modem`).

This provides a local private network and Internet connection to the wireless and wired computer and devices connected to the `Linksys router`.

Two cables are connected to the RJ45 Network switch (in this case the `PCNet 8 port switch`).  One from the `Arris DG860 Cable Modem` and one from the `Linksys router`.  Now any device connected to the RJ45 network switch can either have a static WAN (public IP) connection to the Internet, or a static private IP to the local devices, or a DHCP (dynamic) private IP connection to the local network (provided by the Linksys Router) and the Internet via the Linksys Router's gateway.

*I'll update this configuration periodically for clarity.  I hope others having WAN static IP's can benefit from this solution.*